# Generate special javascript function within razor

Tags: razor

[My problem's image](http://oi60.tinypic.com/96m0ky.jpg)

For example: I have di.ID=3ee93ac8, and I wanna create js function which has name fnc_3ee93ac8(). So I use fnc_@di.ID() but syntax error. Someone can help, thank you very much.

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnDwn_@di.ID").on('click', function () {

});
function fnc_@di.ID(){
    $.Dialog({
        overlay: true,
        shadow: true,
        flat: true,
        width: 500,
        title: 'Download',
        content: '<div id="divDwn_@di.ID"><img class="centre" src="Resources/images/loading.gif" /></div>',
        onShow: function (_dialog) {
            $("#divDwn_@di.ID").load('ajGetData/GetLinkDown?cid=@di.ID');
        }
    });        
}</script>
```

Comment: what is 'di' here id in there in your Model isn't???

Comment: I have 'di', no matter with that variable, I declared it. '$("#btnDwn_@di.ID")' run extractly. di.ID is a property, I think I cannot use "()" after, but I dont know how to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just correct this line

```
 function fnc_@di.ID(){
```

by this

```
 function fnc_@(di.ID)(){
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It's so easy :((